# Creating a new Sheet instead of using existing sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I am copying data from one workbook to another workbook. The problem is pandas is creating a new sheet in the with the name 'sheet_name1' instead of using 'sheet_name'. I am using openpyxl as the Pandas Engine. Can you help with the reason?

```
    input_file = "C:\Automations\FastenersAudit\ClassfiedExports\\" + str(export)
    output_file = "C:\Automations\FastenersAudit\Templates\\" + str(template)

    input_df = pd.read_excel(io=input_file, skiprows=1)
    output_df = pd.read_excel(io=output_file, skiprows=4)
    headings = list(output_df.head())
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine="openpyxl")
    writer.book = openpyxl.load_workbook(output_file)

    for each_heading in headings:
        try:
            output_df[each_heading] = input_df[each_heading]
        except KeyError:
            continue

    output_df = output_df.loc[:, :'Total Attributes']
    output_df = output_df.drop(labels='Total Attributes', axis=1)
    output_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Attribute Analysis", na_rep='', index=False, startrow=5, engine="openpyxl")
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

Comment: so you want `Attribute Analysis` as sheet name but getting `Attribute Analysis1` as sheet name?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I have some data in that sheet. I want to add to that. But, it is creating a new sheet with the name Attribute Analysis1

Comment: try `startrow = writer.sheets['Attribute Analysis'].max_row`  do you have only 1 sheet or multiple sheets??

Comment: I am getting a `KeyError` which indicates the sheet is missing. But, I can open the book manually and see that it has the sheet. 

Printing out sheets `print(writer.sheets)` also returns an empty set `{}`.

Comment: i think some space isues may be, try this.. ??                               `writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}

for sheetname in writer.sheets:
    output_df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheetname, startrow=writer.sheets[sheetname].max_row, index = False,header= False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly Edited Version:
Thank you so much for your solution. It worked perfectly with a slight modification.

```
    writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}

    for sheetname in writer.sheets:
        if sheetname == 'Attribute Analysis':
            output_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, na_rep='', index=False, startrow=5, engine="openpyxl", header=False)
    writer.save()
```

Original Answer:

i think you would need startrow and maxrow functions together along with`writer.sheets` to read the sheetname:

```
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets} 
for sheetname in writer.sheets:

output_df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheetname,startrow=writer.sheets[sheetname].max_row, index = False,header= False)
writer.save()
```